# COUNT function for files?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Is it possible to use `COUNT` in some way that will give me the number of tuples that are in a .sql file? I tried using it in a query with the file name like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @q65b;
```

It tells me that the table is invalid, which I understand because it isn't a table, `q65b` is a file with a query saved in it. I'm trying to compare the number of rows in q65b to a view that I have created. Is this possible or do I just have to run the query and check the number of rows at the bottom?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use a filename to select from. You need a table-like structure (table, view, constant...)

Comment: +1. I don't understand why someone -1'd this. I think the answer is "there's no way", but if there *is* a way, I'd find it very useful!

Comment: (Note, by the way, that "q65b is a file with a query saved in it" is not exactly true: it's a file containing a SQL*Plus script, and that SQL*Plus script consists of a single query.)

Comment: Have you considered reading the file and doing a execute immediate on the query? If there is only one query inside that file and no other stuff it should be easy. Otherwise you would have to identify which query you wanted to execute. To read/write files please check [UTL_FILE](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/UTL_FILE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do this in SQL*Plus. For example:

1. Create the text file, containing the query (note: no semicolon!):

   ```
   select * from dual
   ```
2. Save it in a file, e.g. `myqueryfile.txt`, to the folder accessible from your SQL*Plus session.
3. You can now call this from within another SQL query - but make sure the @ as at the start of a line, e.g.:

   ```
   SQL> select * from (
     2  @myqueryfile.txt
     3  );

   D
   -
   X
   ```

I don't personally use this feature much, however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.  It's a function which reads a file in a directory, wraps the contents in a `select count(*) from ( .... )` construct and executes the resultant statement.

```
  1  create or replace function get_cnt
  2      ( p_file in varchar2 )
  3      return number
  4  as
  5      n pls_integer;
  6      stmt varchar2(32767);
  7      f_line varchar2(255);
  8      fh utl_file.file_type;
  9  begin
 10      stmt := 'select count(*) from (';
 11      fh := utl_file.fopen('SQL_SCRIPTS', p_file, 'R');
 12      loop
 13          utl_file.get_line(fh, f_line );
 14          if f_line is null then exit;
 15          elsif f_line = '/' then exit;
 16          else stmt := stmt ||chr(10)||f_line;
 17          end if;
 18      end loop;
 19      stmt := stmt || ')';
 20      execute immediate stmt into n;
 21      return n;
 22* end get_cnt;
SQL>
```

Here is the contents of a sql file:

```
select * from emp
/


~                                                                                                                                                              
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"scripts/q_emp.sql" 3L, 21C
```

And here is how the script runs:

```
SQL>  select get_cnt ('q_emp.sql') from dual
  2  /

GET_CNT('Q_EMP.SQL')
--------------------
                  14

SQL>
```

So it works.  Obviously what I have posted is just a proof of concept.  You will need to include lots of error handling for the UTL_FILE aspects - [it's a package which can throw lots of exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1004619) - and probably some safety checking of the script that gets passed.